# swap root view Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

is there any way to release rootViewController in UInavigationController and set new view Controller as a root View Controller ???

Comment: why would actually you want to do such a thing? There is a way, but it is not that neat. and i wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`setViewControllers:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/setViewControllers%3aanimated%3a) to change view controllers that are in the navigation controller's stack. The root view controller is at index 0.